# What does genfstab's -p option do?

Tags: arch-linux, fstab

While following [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners%27_guide) guide to installing Arch Linux the reader is instructed to execute the following command:

```
genfstab -U -p /mnt >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

It is stated the the `-U` option uses UUID's over labels, but what does the `-p` option do? I have Googled it and can only find a page on fstab itself, not its generator. Arch includes no manpage on the subject... if anyone knows where docs on `genfstab` are, can they please provide a link? If not, can someone tell me what the options are or what the options do (primarily the `-p` switch)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As stated in the "usage" section, `-p` will skip pseudo-FS mounts (tmpfs, AutoFS and others):

> usage: genfstab [options] root
>
> Options:
>    -L       Use labels for source identifiers (shortcut for -t LABEL)
>    -p       Avoid printing pseudofs mounts (default behavior)
>    -t TAG      Use TAG for source identifiers
>    -U       Use UUIDs for source identifiers (shortcut for -t UUID)
>
> -h       Print this help message
>
> genfstab generates output suitable for addition to an fstab file based
>   on the devices mounted under the mountpoint specified by the given
>   root.

You can check the details in its source code: [genfstab.in - arch-install-scripts.git | Official arch-install-scripts repository](https://projects.archlinux.org/arch-install-scripts.git/tree/genfstab.in)

Comment: is that a man page? is the problem simply that arch doesnt include the man for this command? or was this obtained from the provided link?

Comment: Yes, Arch doesn't provide man-page for genfstab. And you can get this if you run `genfstab` without parameters or `genfstab -h`. It's quite common for short scripts to contains full usage explanation (because there is too few options to bother with man).